# how can I assign a value to "this" without constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, this

This seems to be pretty simple I would think but I am getting confused by call, apply, bind. etc.

I have an eventListener

```
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    j = 0;
    userTurn();
})
```

and I am passing in the function userTurn()

```
function userTurn() {
    if (this === colors[pattern[j]]) {
        console.log("correct")
        j++;
    }
    else {
        console.log('wrong');
    }
```

All I want is the this keyword to apply to the element that the eventListener is on, but it is defaulting to the window object.  I am pretty sure this is because I am not binding this to the eventListener but I cant figure it out...

thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please explain what you exactly want to achieve here?

Comment: I have a bunch of eventListeners that need to run this same userTurn() function if clicked, so instead of copy & pasting a bunch I wanted to just pass in the name of the function....I want the "this" keyword to refer to the specific element of whatever eventListener it came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function invoked without a calling context, such as your

```
userTurn();
```

will, by default, have its `this` set to the global (window) object. To call a function while specifying a custom calling context, use `.call`, whose first argument is the custom `this` value you want to set:

```
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    j = 0;
    userTurn.call(this);
})
```

```js
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
  j = 0;
  userTurn.call(this);
})

function userTurn() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div id="red">red</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it when calling `userTurn();`

Like `userTurn(this);`

And then add the parameters to the function.

```
function userTurn(obj){
 if (obj === colors[pattern[j]]) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside a function refers to the `window` `object` if the function does not belong to any object.

So in the below function

```
function userTurn() {
    if (this === colors[pattern[j]]) {
        console.log("correct")
        j++;
    }
    else {
        console.log('wrong');
    }
```

`this` refers to window object as the function `userTurn` is not attached to any object but window object. While in the below code `this` refers to the element from which the event is triggered.

```
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    j = 0;
    userTurn();
})
```

So in this case you can pass the reference of `this` from the `click` handler

```
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let j = 0;
    userTurn(this);
})

function userTurn(anyParamName) {
    if (anyParamName=== colors[pattern[j]]) {
        console.log("correct")
        j++;
    }
    else {
        console.log('wrong');
     }
    }
```